# Adding to sceneGroup - Attempt to index global 'self' (a nil value)

Tags: coronasdk

Yet another problem with sceneGroup.

```
local function addScore (event)
local sceneGroup = self.view -- where the error is
```

then later:

```
sceneGroup:insert( scoreStars )
```

local sceneGroup = self.view under scene:create, under sceneLshow(event), local sceneGroup = self.view, scene:hide( event ) and at the start of the lua file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In functions like `scene:something` you get hidden parameter `self` which reference to `scene` itself. In those cases `scene` == `self`. Outside of those functions you need use `scene.view` assuming `scene` object exists. So in `addScore` function use `scene.view` instead of `self.view`.

More information you find in  [Understanding the colon vs. dot operator](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2015/12/01/tutorial-understanding-the-colon-vs-dot-operator/) or [Introducing the Composer API](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/01/21/introducing-the-composer-api-plus-tutorial/).